# Graph library for playbook

Tags: actionscript-3, graph, air, blackberry-playbook

i need a line chart in my playbook app. does anybody know a library for that? (for as3 mobile air projects)

Answer (score 0):

Your best luck might be to use FXG as Christophe Coenraets is showing [here](http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/09/building-lightweight-mobile-ready-charts-with-fxg/). Otherwise you might try also Steven Peeters pure solution [there](http://www.flexpert.be/2010/12/drawing-charts-in-a-flex-4-5-mobile-application/).

Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest AmCharts for Flex (http://flex.amcharts.com/). I used AmMaps for my first PlayBook application. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found this reply is very useful when I was writing my first chart application for a playbook [Using mx.charts in a Flex Hero mobile project](http://Using%20mx.charts%20in%20a%20Flex%20Hero%20mobile%20project)